# Rails - Specifying days when not to run a command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

I have a method that is run via delayed_job.
There is a field where the user inputs the days they do not want the task to run on e.g

```
days_off = ["Wednesday","Thursday"]
```

whenever a the method is run I want to check if todays day is in the 'days_off' array and if so then add 24hrs to the delayed job

```
if days_off.include? Time.now.strftime("%A")
  Call.delay(run_at: (DateTime.now + 24.hours )).my_method(c)
else
  Call.my_method(c)
end
```

however I'm not sure how to check the days_off array for consecutive days, i.e in the example above the method should have a delay of 48hrs as it shouldn't be run on a wednesday (today) or a thursday

Comment: I don't want to cancel any jobs, I just don't want them to run on specific days

Comment: Your code will work as it is - if there are two consecutive "day offs", it will not run `my_method` on either of them - it will simply reschedule...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with something like this:

```
days_off = ["Wednesday","Thursday"]

if days_off.include? Time.now.strftime("%A")
  one_day = 60 * 60 * 24
  next_run = Time.now
  while days_off.include? next_run.strftime("%A")
    next_run = next_run + one_day
  end
  puts "call.delay() with next_run goes here"
else
  puts "call.my_method() goes here"
end
```